# using msgspec in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse a json file using the library [MSGSPEC](https://github.com/jcrist/msgspec) for python.

The information I am trying to get from that json is on one key and the iterables are on that key. I saw examples with clases but I have not been able to replicate that on this kind of json structure. any idea how to iterate over the list that is on that key using the package MSGSPEC in python.

Thanks in Advance

class creation and then parsin the json file using that class

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what issue you are seeing.   The expectation is that you will show the effort you made and then ask for assistance in correcting/understanding it.